# Removing property from one variable affects another variable in Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

While iterating `results` property, assigning it's value to another property `moreResults`, then removing `testDetails` array elements from `moreResults` property. But `testDetails` array elements are removed both from `results` and `moreResults` properties.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.results.length; i++) {
      this.moreResults.push(this.results[i]);
      this.moreResults[i].testDetails = [];
    }
    console.log(this.moreResults);
    console.log(this.results);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/z3ngbo?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdivider-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method to resolve your issue.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread

example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.results.length; i++) {
      this.moreResults.push({...this.results[i]});
      this.moreResults[i].testDetails = [];
    }
    console.log(this.moreResults);
    console.log(this.results);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code moreResults is a copy of results, you need to clone your data

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.moreResults = this.results.map((r:any) => {
  const m = {...r};
    m.testDetails = []
    return m;
  })
  console.log(this.moreResults);
  console.log(this.results);
}
```

see to more details
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course!

`this.results` holds object instances. `this.moreResults.push(this.results[i]);`
adds one of this object instances to `this.moreResults`, however, the object instance is not copied, only the reference is added. Therefore, you are editing the same object instance when doing `this.moreResults[i].testDetails = [];` or doing `this.results[i].testDetails = [];`

Use `this.moreResults.push({...this.results[i]});` to actually copy the object instance.